# How to perform cell validation in #ag-grid for React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-validation

I have started using ag-grid in my react project, and was unable to find any API's for performing in-line cell validations i.e. whenever user edits a particular cell, the requirement is to perform a required field and pattern validation. In case of any validation errors, the corresponding editable field should get highlighted and an error message needs to be displayed.

I have used the following cell events to fulfill the above purpose, but none of them provided me the desired result.

cellEditingStarted

cellEditingStopped

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the `valueParser` option on the column definition for the column that you are editing.  Here is an example where I have used it in the past:

```
            valueParser: (params: ValueParserParams) => {
                try {
                    let index = users.indexOf(params.newValue);
                    return index > -1 ? index : null;
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

Personally, I usually would use `onCellValueChanged` for performing validations, which is a property on the grid directly.